# Read in file in C, put contents into buffer, get case in the buffer instead

Tags: c, server, client

I dont understand where case is coming from and its driving me up the wall. Im trying to do a client/ sever where i send the file through a socket to the server. It used to be able to store the file but now it just says case instead of the file contents. Also whenever I send over this text to the server the server doesnt even put case into a file, it just creates file.txt in a folder and then at the root makes a garbage file that has a broken file name.

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
//#include<sys/types.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int SID;
    int gid,uid,ueid,geid;
    gid_t *groups;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    //Create socket
    SID =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(SID == -1)
    {
        printf("Error creating socket");
    }else{
        printf("Socket created");
    }
    //set sockaddr_in variables
    server.sin_port =htons ( 8081 );//port to connect on
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");//server ip
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;//ipv4 protocol

    //connect to server
    if(connect(SID, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))<0)
    {
        printf("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    //uid = 1000;//getuid();
    //gid = 1000;//getgid();
    //ueid = geteuid();
    //geid = getegid();

    //printf("%d\n", uid);
    //gid=getgid();
    //printf("%d\n", gid);
    printf("connected to server ok\n");
    char root[] ="Root/"; //remove name root as it will need to be in the root directory
    char sales[] = "Sales/";
    char promotions[] ="Promotions/";
    char offers[] = "Offers/";
    char marketing[] ="Marketing/";
    ///sending file craic
    FILE *f;
    int words =0;
    char c;
    int serverpath;
    char enteredfilename[200];
    char file_name[300];
    printf("Whats the file name?\n");
    scanf("%s", enteredfilename);



    do{
        printf("\n Enter the number of the file destinations\n1. Root\n2. Sales\n3. Promotions\n4. Offers\n5. Marketing\n6. Exit\n");

        scanf("%d", &serverpath);
        switch (serverpath)
        {
            case 1://root
                strcat(root, enteredfilename);
                strcpy(file_name,root);
                break;
            case 2://sales
                strcat(sales, enteredfilename);
                strcpy(file_name,sales);
                break; 
            case 3://promotions
                strcat(promotions, enteredfilename);
                strcpy(file_name,promotions); 
                break;   
            case 4://offers
                strcat(offers, enteredfilename);
                strcpy(file_name,offers);
                break;
            case 5://marketing
                strcat(marketing, enteredfilename);
                strcpy(file_name,marketing);
                break;
            case 6://exit
                printf("Client terminated");
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("Please enter a number between 1-6");
                break;
        }
    }while((serverpath != 1) && (serverpath != 2) && (serverpath != 3) && (serverpath != 4) && (serverpath != 5) && (serverpath != 6));

    f = fopen(enteredfilename, "r");//r just means we are reading it
    if(f == NULL)//if there is no file, it will close
    {
        printf("error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    };

    char buffer[1024];
    while((c = getc(f))!= EOF)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s", buffer);
        if(isspace(c) || c=='\t')
        words++;
    }
    //write(SID, uid, 255);
    //write(SID, gid, 255);
    //write(SID, ueid, 255);
    //write(SID, geid, 255); 
    write(SID, file_name, 255);//sends the file_name to the server

    rewind(f);

    char ch;
    printf("%s", buffer);
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s", buffer);
        if(isspace(c) || c=='\t'){
            strncat(buffer, " ",1);//probably doesnt work
        }
        ch = fgetc(f);

    }

    printf("%s", buffer);
    write(SID, buffer,255);//sends buffer to server
    write(SID, &words, sizeof(int));


    printf("The file has been successfully sent");

    close(SID);
    return 0;
}  ```
````

Comment: You invoke undefined behaviour by using `strcat` on a variable that does not provide enough memory.

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf` and `fscanf` to verify if you read any useful data. Also `write` has a return value you should not ignore.

Comment: That fixed the garbage file issue i think but it doesnt fix the "case" in buffer issue

Comment: What input do you provide? Which options to you select? What content is in those files? At which line do you think `buffer` is not correct`? What should be in `buffer` instead?

Comment: You have some weird code. `filename` can hold 300 bytes but you send 255 without taking care about content. `buffer` can hold up to 1024 bytes and you read without length limit into that buffer. Then you add `' '` and start reading into the begin of that buffer again. Really strange...

Comment: No errors for any of the scanf and fscanf. Why would I check write though, its buffer thats the issue. It used to work before I added the do while. I made all the directory variables 1024 in size and the enterfilename and file_name to 1024, as well as the writes. Still printing case from buffer

Comment: Im gonna be honest, I have no idea what im at in c so im just throwing things in and see if it works

Comment: What is the last word in the file you read?

Comment: I read in "file.txt" as the file name, which is just a text file with some words in it. Buffer is never what its suppose to be

Comment: And what is the last word of those "some words in it"? And what is `buffer`supposed to be?

Comment: Case is the last word.....

Comment: Does that rind a bell? As I mentioned a few comments above you read again at the start of `buffer` after adding `' '`.

Comment: I got this code for reading in the file from some video about file transfer and it worked before. Seems to be taking the last word and I honestly dont understand whats going on in the code anymore

Comment: `fscanf(f, "%s", buffer);` always uses the same place in your buffer. Right at the start. Whatever you have read in earlier iteration of the loop, is lost. This is fine if you handle the content immediately and don't need to store it for later use. If you need to keep it, you must read it in another location.

Comment: I deleted all the code and just started back when the file would transfer over to the server. Seems to be an issue with the server code is it isnt saving the code.